# How to distinguish between button_click(null,null) and an actual click by user

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I am "forcing" a button click from a method with `button_Click(null,null)`

In the `button_Click`method I want to distinguish between an actual click and a forced click (`button_Click(null,null)`).

I was thinking I could use an if statement to check `if (sender.Equals(null))`, but that was just a guess and it didn't work. I'm sorry if this seems like, google me an answer please, but I haven't found anything similar.

Comment: Can you give more context? What causes a button_Click(null, null)? Why do you need to do this anyway?
Your question indicates you're doing something awfully hacky...

Comment: What "didn't work" ? It should have worked and you tell us nothing.

Comment: @Squiggle If a listBox item is clicked it forces a button_click(null,null)

Comment: @HenkHolterman This should work? The app crashed, then it might be something else, I'll figure it out, thanks

Comment: Right, `sender.Equals(null)` will return false or throw. I missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way of handling this is by not even attempting to handle it.

Don't call your event handlers except when the event takes place. Create a reusable method that takes a parameter to indicate whether you have a real button click. Then call it from your `button_Click` event handler with one value, and from a new method with another value.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  HandleButtonClick(isRealClick: true);
}

private void SimulateButtonClick() {
  HandleButtonClick(isRealClick: false);
}

private void HandleButtonClick(bool isRealClick) {
  // ...
}
```

Now, instead of calling `button_Click(null, null)`, call `SimulateButtonClick()`.

The drawback of calling `button_Click(null, null)` is that it is not at all obvious to other people reading your code that your call shouldn't be changed to `button_Click(button, EventArgs.Empty)`. Such a change would break your code. If possible, you should write your code so that it is easy to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing null to the eventargs, just check if it is null (it won't be null if the user actually clicks the button/presses enter to click etc)

```
if(e == null)
{
 // Button was forced
}
```

Comment: sender == null worked, while sender.equals(null) didn't. Thanks!

Comment: @Erra - Is not really different from checking  `sender == null`

Comment: @mythic Either should work, since you're passing null to both, and neither should be null if the button is actually clicked. No problem!